# Instalação Moodle erro de conexão com o banco de dados

Tags: moodle

Estou tentando instalar o moodle local, nunca mexi com ele estou seguindo uns passo a passo porem esta dando o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aonde posso verificar se o usuario do meu BD é realmente root e sem senha?

Obrigado.

**ERRO**

> Erro: Conexão com o banco de dados falhou
>
> É possível que o banco de dados esteja sobrecarregado ou não está
>   funcionando adequadamente
>
> O administrador do site também deve verificar se os dados do banco de
>   dados foram corretamente especificados no config.php
>
> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
>   /Users/usuario/Projetos/moodle/lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php
>   on line 79

Comment: @rray editei a pergunta e coloquei o erro

Comment: Você consegue conecta no mysql com qual usuário e senha? a configuração padrão do moodle deve estar diferente da sua.

Comment: Então eu consigo entrar no phpmyadmin criei o bd la, mas ta entrando direito sem precisar de usuario e senha, talvez ja esteja salvo e eu nao lembro =/ @rray

Comment: Na pasta do phpmyAdmin, tenta achar esse arquivo `config.inc.php` lá tem uma configuração de usuário e senha, use essa para o moodle, deve funcionar. Pode se basear por [essa questão](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2703996/1342547)

Comment: @rray  deu certooo man ... coloca como resposta, peguei os dados la do arquivo e deu tudo certo. Muito obrigado.